# WiX compatibility with Windows Installer versions (schemas)

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3, wix2

What are the minimum [version requirements for Windows Installer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer#Versions) ("Schema" version?) version that WiX imposes in the created setup databases?

I.e. for the following versions of WiX, what (database "Schema") version of Windows Installer is the minimum requirement on the target system?

- WiX 2.0
- WiX 3.0
- WiX 3.5
- WiX 3.6
- WiX 3.7
- WiX 3.8

NB: What I am referring to is, I think, called "Schema" in the "Summary Information" for a setup database:

[image: The field that governs compatibility of an MSI with Windows Installer]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, found the answer. It appears all of the mentioned WiX versions support at least `InstallerVersion="200"` [in the `<Package />` element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/package.html). To quote the relevant part of the above documentation page:

> The minimum version of the Windows Installer required to install this
>   package. Take the major version of the required Windows Installer and
>   multiply by a 100 then add the minor version of the Windows Installer.
>   For example, "200" would represent Windows Installer 2.0 and "405"
>   would represent Windows Installer 4.5. For 64-bit Windows Installer
>   packages, this property is set to 200 by default as Windows Installer
>   2.0 was the first version to support 64-bit packages.

According to the Wikipedia article linked in the question this version of Windows Installer (i.e. 2.0) was included with:

- Windows XP RTM, SP1
- Windows 2000 SP3, SP4
- Windows Server 2003 RTM

and is available for:

- Windows 95/98/Me
- Windows NT 4.0 SP6
- Windows 2000 RTM, SP1, SP2

So **in conclusion** we can say that the minimum supported version of Windows Installer for a WiX-authored setup is: 2.0 (== `InstallerVersion="200"`).